# Does this op-amp circuit have a name?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I got asked to analyze this circuit during a past interview, and truth be told, I still don't have a good understanding on what it is and how it's intended to work.

[image]

I understand V+ = Vout/2 and V- is an RC circuit related to Vout.

I assume V+ and V- are meant to be differential.

I also know that the op-amp will adjust Vout to make the voltage at the inverting and non-inverting terminals the same. If you could refer me to this circuit, I'll do my own research and be on my merry way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's an opamp-comparator-based relaxation oscillator.

In a nutshell, charging source of the capacitor alternates between +V<sub>DD</sub> and –V<sub>SS</sub>, and the frequency of the cycle is determined by the R and C components:

$$
\mathrm{f = \frac{1}{2\cdot \ln(3)\cdot RC}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I believe you are right - it is an op-amp oscillator. Cheers!

Comment: @laurakoco you can accept my answer if it's satisfactory enough, so that the question does not remain open.